# Regex to convert enum field value to json

Tags: php, json, enums, mysqli

Is there a way to quickly convert simple enum data format like this

enum('one','two','three')

to json?

I wrote a code:

```
        $res = $rst->fetch_assoc();
        $type = $res['DATA_TYPE'];
        $json = preg_replace('/\'/','"', $res['COLUMN_TYPE']);
        $json = preg_replace("/^$type\(/",'[', $json);
        $json = preg_replace('/\)/',']', $json);
        return json_decode($json);
```

But here 3 substitutes for each part of original string: single quotes, 'enum( ' and ')'. I have read a lot about regex for converting enum but could not figure out how to do it in one leap.

Comment: How do you want your enums to be formatted in json? Just an array?

Comment: As usual ["one", "two", "three"] --- Code above is working, I just would to know the shortest way.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this, it should have the desired result

```
$res = $rst->fetch_assoc();
$type = $res['DATA_TYPE'];
preg_match_all('/\'([^\']*)\'/',$res['COLUMN_TYPE'],$matches);
return $matches[1];
```

you said you wanted json, but you are actually using json_decode() at the end to return an array, preg_match_all already gives you an array, so no need for decoding, if you actually want json, you could just use `json_encode($matches[1])`

Answer (score 0):

This should work out for you.

```
<?php
$str = "enum('one','two','three')";
$start = strpos($str, "(")+1;
$str = substr($str, $start, strrpos($str,")") - $start);
$parts = explode(",", $str);
$enum = array_map(function($a){
        return trim($a, "'");
    },$parts);
return json_encode($enum);
```